# Multiplying Orders of Elements

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

Let $a$ and $b$ be elements of a group $G$ such that $\vert a\vert = p^i$ and $\vert b \vert = p^j$ for a prime number $p$ and integers $i$ and $j$.
Is it true that $\vert a\vert *\vert b\vert = \vert ab\vert = p^{i+j}$?

Answer (score 2):

No - an easy counterexample is $G=S_3$ (the symmetric group on $3$ generators), with $a=(12)$ and $b=(23)$, so that $|a|=|b|=2$ but $|ab|=|(123)|=3$. Note that $|ab|$ is not any power of $2$.

Comment: Curious isn't $1$ in $\mathbb{Z}_2$ a "simpler" counterexample?

Comment: @Gage: Fair enough, though I guess it may still give the impression that $|ab|$ must be some power of the same prime $p$.

Comment: good point and nice choice of a counterexample